What would an inter-universal medium be like?
I don't really believe in the Multiverse Theory, but hypothetically, if universes were like soap bubbles in a foam, what might that foam be like? I know this seems like an opinion-based question but what might the properties of true nothingness be based on what we know about the fabric of the universe? Would there be no gravity or some other repulsive force? Would there be high-energy states instead of zero energy? Complete nothingness without a single particle (true vacuum)?

Voting to reopen. Eternal inflation models are definitely studied in mainstream physics.

Agreed, this has an answer in the context of eternal inflation.

In the context of eternal inflation models, the energy density throughout most of spacetime is dominated by the inflaton field, which drives accelerated expansion (through its gravitational repulsion). However, there are regions in which the inflaton field has changed its state, transitioning into something like matter or radiation. Our Universe would be one such region.
Here is a conceptual spacetime diagram of what this should look like. The Universe is bounded by the future light cone of some origination event. I've drawn also the spacetime grid (gray solid and dashed lines) of the Universe.

(Mathematically I'm actually showing a Milne cosmology, which is not correct but conveys the concepts well enough and is simpler to think about, since its spacetime is flat.)
Within this framework, the "inter-universal medium" is part of the same 4-dimensional spacetime as our own Universe. However, we can never escape from our Universe to see it, since the edge of the Universe recedes at the speed of light. In fact, in my depiction, our Universe is spatially infinite; this can be seen by the fact that the number of "time threads" (solid gray lines), which I plotted at fixed spatial intervals, is unbounded.
Physics in the "inter-universal medium" would be very different from in our Universe, though. Assuming an inflation energy scale around $10^{-6}$ the Planck mass, inflaton-driven gravitational repulsion would be so strong that the cosmological event horizon would be only around $10^{12}$ Planck lengths, or around $10^{-23}$ meters (see this answer). Anything larger than that would necessarily be torn apart, due to its different portions being causally disconnected.

What about the possibility that the universe is indeed a vast yet finite structure that sits in ocean of a medium of  a purer vacuum that is more or less devoid of any of the elements that make up our universe, including the Planck level soup to Galactic filaments. Stuff at the edge of the universe would move faster at the edges as it evaporates into the more perfect vacuum.

Multiverse comparison with bubbles in the foam is certainty incorrect. Bubbles and foam is in the same $3D$ space, so all the bubbles are causally connected according to $ct$ metrics. While universes in the multiverse theory are causally disconnected by all means, which means that no medium, nor any form of spacetime connects those separate universe "bubbles". This is why multiverse theory is on the edge on scientific credibility,- there's no way to get proof of other universes existing "in the same batch".
However, in the name of scientific curiosity, there were spotted neutrino streams from ANITA-I/III Antarctic experiments where neutrinos were also registered coming at steep angles from below the Earth surface. These events are still not explained, as standard model says that such neutrino source should be highly attenuated by Earth planet. Hence, besides possible rational explanations that such backwards neutrinos were generated in Antarctic ice itself (for still unknown reason),- there exists also "irrational" or exotic explanations that these neutrinos were generated from say "alternate universe" where time is going backwards. But how and why this "alternate universe to be" is causally connected to our universe - would be another unexplained mystery.
So the best short answer to your question would be that there can't be any type of medium "between" universes (nor space, neither vacuum, nor anything), because it effectively would destroy true multiverse theory,- i.e. common environment would join all universes into single global universe.
